# Remote Desktop Protocol C or Objective-C Library

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, remote-desktop

Does anyone know of a library for RDP that's written in C or Objective-C that is not GPLed?

Comment: Can you not find one with an LGPL license?

Comment: I only found ones with a GPL license.

Comment: Sun supplies a uttsc utility for use with their SunRay graphical terminal. Much of Sun's software is now open source, but I couldn't immediately find the uttsc source. It might be worth some more Googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer for CoRD, which is a Cocoa RDP client based off rdesktop. There are no loosely-licensed RDP implementations to my knowledge. As far as I know, rdesktop is your best bet (GPL).

Very detailed RDP protocol documents are freely available from Microsoft, however it is a somewhat difficult protocol to implement from scratch, due to its lengthy history and myriad of additions. It's much harder to implement than say, RFB.