# I would like to develop application like "Desktop Connect" for iPad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, networking

I searched little bit but with no luck. I just need where to begin or the guideline or tutorials through which I can proceed for application development like "**Desktop Connect**".

It allows to connect desktop computers remotely from iPad and access it like you are working on your desktop.

Any Thoughts or assistance will be highly appreciated.

Jennis.

Comment: Start with reading up on the various remote desktop protocols, like VNC/RFB, RDP, FreeNX, maybe even X11 forwarding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop

Comment: Why not write a new app instead of a clone of existing function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the part in which you need assistance ? Protocol, mouse/keyboard emulation, ...

Anyway there is an open source RDP client for iPhone/iPad available !
You can get source code here :
http://www.irdesktop.com/gpl/

From this code, you could learn a lot about how it is done and how you could do something on the iPad ! But it's licensed under the GPL, so using any code from this application will force you to license your application under the GPL too.

Comment: and since it's GPL an app that uses it can't be published in the app store without violating the GPL.

Comment: Good point, even if there are plenty of GPLv2 applications available on the appStore ...

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at implementing the Remote Deskop Protocol (often refer to as RDP).

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019236/remote-desktop-protocol-c-or-objective-c-library) has some basic start info on that protocol that may help you.

And as pointed by Piskvor, there are other protocols, the most widely used being VNC.