# How to Develop/implement a Remote Desktop app for iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, remote-desktop, rdp

I have been trying to search a lot online on this but most of the links are not explaining how to implement.

Some questions to start with:

1. Which API should I use to develop RDP app for iPad to connect to
   windows/Mac machine?
2. Also, when the remote machine is connected I want to launch an
   application on that machine automatically.
3. Is the Microsoft RDP API useful for developing iPad remote
   desktop app? If so, can anybody provide some tutorials or suggest an approach?

I've read these questions but they don't explain it sufficiently:

[Remote Desktop Protocol C or Objective-C Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019236/remote-desktop-protocol-c-or-objective-c-library)

[I would like to develop application like "Desktop Connect" for iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804209/i-would-like-to-develop-application-like-desktop-connect-for-ipad-app)