# RDP implementation options on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rdp

Are there any descent RDP libraries/implementations for iOS platform usage?

If you should do it regardless of them being any, how would you do it? Maybe start diggin' into/porting code from freeRDP? What about those dependencies on Xorg and ALSA stuff? How can you render stuff on the iPhone coming from raw RDP data?

Comment: cord (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cord/) appears to be written in objective c and c.  or check out a java implementation: properJavaRDP (http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

From [similar stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019236/remote-desktop-protocol-c-or-objective-c-library):

> I'm a developer for CoRD, which is a Cocoa RDP client based off
>   rdesktop. There are no loosely-licensed RDP implementations to my
>   knowledge. As far as I know, rdesktop is your best bet (GPL).
>
> Very detailed RDP protocol documents are freely available from
>   Microsoft, however it is a somewhat difficult protocol to implement
>   from scratch, due to its lengthy history and myriad of additions. It's
>   much harder to implement than say, RFB.